# android logo height in action bar not match action bar height

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Currently, my logo height in action bar doesn't match the action bar height.

[image]

The following is my style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTab</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTabBar</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_bar</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/logo</item>
</style>
```

Also, I tried to add the logo icon in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

But the height of the logo still doesn't match the height of the action bar.

Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Eric

Comment: Looks like action bar's padding.

Comment: I found if I set a custom view for the action bar programmatically, and make the logo ImageView's height match parent, it will work.

Comment: @Eric May If you solved your issue, please answer your question.